# Display data to view from route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I want to display the total count of unread messages of the user, so I created separate function on that:

```
public function getCountMessage($user_id)
{
    ....
    return $count;
}
```

My route to access that function:

```
Route::get('/message_count/{user_id}', [
    'uses' => 'MessageController@getCountMessage',
    'as' => 'count.message',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

And I have `header.blade.php` (will be inherited into `master.blade.php`) to display the total count of unread messages.

```
<li><a href="#">Messages <span class="label label-pill label-danger">{{ route('count.message', ['user_id' =>  Auth::user()->id]) }}</span></a></li>
```

But the output is

[image]

I want the output to look like this:

Messages (1)

I want to output the return of that route in my `span`, is this possible or any idea how to achieve this? Btw, I've done some research and can't find a solution.

Note that `header.blade.php` is an includes file only. It means that no one is returning this as a view. Hope you get what I mean.

Other similar example, i retrieve my image like this:

Blade:

```
<img src="{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => $user->profile_picture_path]) }}">
```

Controller:

```
return new Response($file, 200);
```

The value of image is coming from `route`

Comment: you need to show url to user ?

Comment: I need to show the count or return of that function (Example: 1)

Comment: then pass your data to view from controller.
go to your controller getCountMessage function change return to this :
return view('yourview')->with('count',$count).
in view : use this to print count {{$count}}

Comment: You're right on how to pass variable in view, but my problem is `header.blade.php` is an include file only, no one is returning this as a view. Hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

First pass data from controller to view :

```
public function MessageController(){
    ....
    return view('yourView')->with('count',$count);
}
```

then if you have partial View like header, no problem its ok use @include in your main view.

- view

  - partial

    - header.blade.php
  - yourView.blade.php

include your patrial on yourView.blade.php :

```
@include('header')
```

show your count data in header.blade.php with this :

```
{{$count}}
```

or you can write codes direct on header.blade.php :

```
@php
   $count = Auth:user()->id;
@endphp

{{$count}}
```

Comment: This will works, but i need to recreate those count in every controller that has partial `header` or this is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

You can return `$count` in your blade file like:

```
public function getCountMessage($user_id)
{
    ....
    return view('view',compact(count));
}
```

And change your blade file code like :

```
<li><a href="#">Messages <span class="label label-pill label-danger">{{$count}}</span></a></li>
```

Hope this help for you.

Comment: And the how I can access `getCountMessage` function? Note that `header.blade.php` is an includes file only. Hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, but I don't if this is the best. I used jQuery to send an Http request to my route like this and change the innerHTML of my span.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var theUrl = "{{ route('count.message', ['user_id' =>  Auth::user()->id]) }}"
        $.get(
            theUrl,                
            function(data) {
                document.getElementById("message_count").innerHTML = data;

                if (data == 0) {
                    $('#message_count').removeClass('label-danger');
                    $('#message_count').addClass('label-default');                        
                }                   
            }
        );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the count function in laraval, for example, this:

If you pass a variable in your view. In my case a user. U can use:
`{{ $user->topics->count() }}` It shows the amount of topics that belong to that certain user.

In your case, that should be something long the lines of

`{{ $user->messages->count() }}` Depends on how your database table is called. And if/or these two have a relation in the model

I hope this helps you,

Comment: That's the normal case which is passing a variable in view, my case is I need to pass the variable in partial view `header.blade.php`